# How I use fields on a custom template?

Tags: entities

I'm attempting to build custom template for specific content type.
So, I created `node--my-content-type.tpl.php` and tried to write some text: it works!
Ok, now I want to render my fields. I have `$content['field_title']`, `field_author`, `field_cast` (is a field collection) etc.

I need values of these fields, so I tried to assign some variables:
`$title = $content['field_title']['value']` etc, but it doesn't seem to work.
I can only call render function to render these fields, but I want to format page in custom mode.

How can I get field info in order to use correct values?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and enable the devel module to use `dpm()` on `$content`. This will show you the proper structure of the `$content` array. Sometimes entities and fields will have different structures depending on their type or how they're being implemented for that content type.